# JavaFX - TableView - Populate cell with text from multiple properties

Tags: java, javafx

I think this isn't such a hard problem, but I can't get my head around it. Basiclly it gets down to this:

I have a [TableView](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/control/TableView.html) that is populated with objects from the model class Foo:

```
class Foo {
    private StringProperty textColA;
    private StringProperty textColB1;
    private StringProperty textColB2;

    // Getters, setters and properties left away
}
```

The first column just gets it's data from the `textColA` StringProperty. Column B on the other hand needs both the data from `textColB1`and `textColB2`. Is it possible to create some sort of property that wraps these two?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure. For example, to produce a concatenation of the two strings with a space between, do

```
TableColumn<Foo, String> someColumn = new TableColumn<>("Column");
someColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> Bindings.createStringBinding(() ->
    cellData.getValue().getTextColB1() + " " + cellData.getValue().getTextColB2(),
    cellData.textColB1Property(), cellData.textColB2Property()));
```

(more simply in this particular case, you could do

```
someColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData ->
    cellData.getValue().textColB1Property().concat(" ")
        .concat(cellData.getValue().textColB2Property());
```

but the more general form will work for arbitrary functions of the two properties).

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I needed. I think you mean `setCellValueFactory` instead of `setCellValueProperty`.